# How to say "must" as a deduction?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Comment puis-je exprimer l'idée d'une déduction en français dont la correspondance en anglais est *must* ?

Par exemple:

> Ah! I see. You must be exhausted after such a long work!

En français, est-ce que c'est avec le verbe `devoir` ?

> Ah ! Je vois. Tu **dois** être épuisé après tel longtemps de travail !`

Est-ce que c'est correct ?

Comment: Autrement dit, je veut exprimer l'idée de `Je crois que tu es épuisé` ou `Je pense que c'est certain que tu sois épuisé`. Merci !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, ***must*** est très bien rendu par "**devoir**" dans cet exemple :

> Ah ! Je vois. Tu dois être épuisé après un si long travail !